# AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'up'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to move the character on my screen up and down.

When I run the code and press the down key, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'down'
```

When I run the code and press the up key, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'up'
```

My Code:

```
#! python3

import pygame

class Ship():
    """A class intended for the management of a spacecraft"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Spaceship initialization and its initial position."""

        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        #Load a spaceship image and retrieve its rectangle.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Each new ship appears in the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

        #The ship's horizontal position is stored as a floating point number.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        #Options that indicate the movement of the ship
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on the option that indicates its movement."""

        #Updating the X coordinate of the ship, not its rectangle
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

       
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.up > 0:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.down > self.screen_rect.down:
            self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed

        
        #Updating rect based on self.x
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def blitme(self):
        """Displaying a spaceship in its current position."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have the feeling that I am doing something wrong in this snippet of code?

```
    if self.moving_up and self.rect.up > 0:
        self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
    if self.moving_down and self.rect.down > self.screen_rect.down:
        self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
```

Comment: In your code, where it says `self.rect.up`, in your own words, what are you expecting that to mean? What do you expect `self.rect` to be, and why does it make sense to you, to look for the `.up` of the result?

Comment: There are no attributes like up or down that are used in Rect object. Did you mean top and bottom attributes?

Comment: I need to go through the documentation again. Definitely.Either I missed it or I didn't remember it. My mistake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has the virtual attributes `top` and `bottom`, but not the attributes `up` and `down`:

```py
if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
    self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
    self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
```

---

Anyway, I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect.clamp_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip):

> Returns a new rectangle that is moved to be completely inside the argument Rect.

With this function, an object can be kept completely in the window:

```py
self.rect.x = self.x
self.rect.y = self.y

if self.moving_right:
    self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
if self.moving_left:
    self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
if self.moving_up:
    self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
if self.moving_down:
    self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed

self.rect.clamp_ip(self.screen_rect)
self.x = self.rect.x
self.y = self.rect.y
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted this code:

```
if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
    self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > self.screen_rect.bottom:
    self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work as needed.
Now when I press the UP button the character moves down and disappears behind the screen.
Nothing happens when the DOWN button is pressed. Unless the character has moved down, then I can use this button to return to the starting position.

Only when I changed to this code it worked:

```
if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
    self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
    self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
```

As for the pygame.Rect.clamp_ip () method:
When it comes to learning for the future. Where exactly should I copy it and what should I delete to make it work? Because I tried, but after copying the code, the character did not move at all.

Comment: Hi.  This doesn't look like an answer to the original question.  If one of the other answers addressed your question, as asked, you should accept it.  If you have additional questions, you should post new questions and ask them.